# how to build a many-to-many relationship using the SQL Expression language

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

On [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769366/why-is-sqlalchemy-insert-with-sqlite-25-times-slower-than-using-sqlite3-directly) from the creator of Sqlalchemy I'm attempting to write my initial bulk insert of data using the  [SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/tutorial.html). See for details.

The tutorial covers a what i assume to be an example of a one-to-many relationship between User and Address. They create the relationship by with the use of the executemany() method:

```
>>> conn.execute(addresses.insert(), [ 
...    {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@yahoo.com'},
...    {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@msn.com'},
...    {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'www@www.org'},
...    {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'wendy@aol.com'},
... ])
INSERT INTO addresses (user_id, email_address) VALUES (?, ?)
((1, 'jack@yahoo.com'), (1, 'jack@msn.com'), (2, 'www@www.org'), (2, 'wendy@aol.com'))
COMMIT
<sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy object at 0x...>
```

How ever in my design i have several many-to-many relationships. One being between User and Organization. Note i'm using [Flask-Sqlalchemy.](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/)

```
# assuming a relationship like:

# organizations = db.Table('organizations',
#         db.Column('organization_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organization.id')),
#         db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')))
# class User(db.Model):
#     ...
#     organizations = db.relationship('Organization', secondary=organizations,
#         backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# class Organization(db.Model):
#     ...

def db_reset():
    # lets reset it
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    # establish our connection
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    conn = engine.connect()

    # load in our users
    user_insert = User.__table__insert()
    for user in users: # users is a list of named tuples
        conn.execute(user_insert, name=user.name, role=user.role, 
            organizations= [orgA,orgB,...etc] # how do i do this?
```

So my question is contained in my code as well as my title. How can a build a many to many relationship in using the SQL Expression Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should certainly still be defining everything, including your many-to-many relationship, using the ORM.   The ORM rides on top of the SQL expression language.  So for that one use case where you need to do a mass insert, you make use of the underlying `Table` object in conjunction with `insert()`, but when you're doing anything else, you stick with regular ORM patterns.