# measuring the insert time and query time on mysql-server using sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have a python program using sqlalchemy that accesses the databse running a remote server.The remote server has mysql-server5.5 running on it.The relevant portions of the code is given below.

```
log = core.getLogger()

engine = create_engine('mysql://root@192.168.129.139/nwtopology', echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String(32),index=True)

    #-----------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address    
    self.port_no     = port_no


#create tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

#query code   
r_res = session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.src)).first()

#insert code
entry = SourcetoPort(src_address=str(packet.src) , port_no=packet_in.in_port)
#add the record to the session object
session.add(entry)
#add the record to the session object
session.commit()
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start
```

I have calculate the average query and insert time over 64-entries to the database.

The average query time was found to be  .001424 seconds

The average insert time was found to be  .03144 seconds

This means you can do a maximum of  32 inserts a second OR 702 queries a second.

Does these numbers look reasonable.I am very new to databases and sqlalchemy.My program needs a much higher number of inserts and quries.Also the number of entries per table and number of tables itself is going to increase significantly.This is the bare minumum prototype with minimum number of entries and one table.

My question is this the kind of performance once can expect from a database.?If not what is the expected performance ? Are there any known mechanisms to speed up the process.? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading my answer to [Why is SQLAlchemy insert with sqlite 25 times slower than using sqlite3 directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769366/why-is-sqlalchemy-insert-with-sqlite-25-times-slower-than-using-sqlite3-directly/11769768#11769768).  It explains in depth the varieties of INSERT to use with DBAPIs, SQLAlchemy Core, and SQLAlchemy ORM, including the differences in use cases and performance.