# SQLAlchemy: Efficiently adding rows with relationships

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy

This is a toy example of my problem. I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship, defined in an SQLAlchemy model as follows:

```
class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    author_name = Column(String(32))
    articles = relationship('Article', back_populates='author')

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    author_id = Column('author', Integer, ForeignKey('authors.id'))
    author = relationship('Author', back_populates='articles')
    article_text = Column(String)
```

When I add a new post, an author's name is passed in as a string in the `Article.author` field. When adding an article to the database, to create a link between it and the author, I check to see if the user exists by querying with the username, and then obtain the model object for that user:

```
def get_user(post, session):
    if session.query(exists().where(User.username==post.user)).scalar():
        user = session.query(User).filter_by(username=post.user).first()
        post.user = user
    return post

def insert_post(post, session):
    post = get_user(post, session)
    try:
        session.add(row)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

This works fine, but it is slow (tens of minutes for inserting around 200,000 articles). In case it helps to know, I'm using MySQL.

I feel like I'm either making unnecessary queries, or have misunderstood how to make ForeignKey relationships work. Or perhaps this is totally normal?

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11769768/341730) from the author of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thanks @univerio. That's very useful. I should also mention that previously, I was inserting articles without checking for and retrieving authors, and the process was much faster.